# List.zip F# Command

Tags: list, f#

Show the institution and the subject where at least 100% of students agree or strongly agreed with the question 12

```
let Q6 =
  data |> List.filter (fun r -> question r = 12)
       |> List.filter (fun r -> score r >= 100)
       |> List.map institution

let Q6i =
  data |> List.filter (fun r -> question r = 12)
       |> List.filter (fun r -> score r >= 100)
       |> List.map subject 
       |> List.zip Q6
```

Could anyone possibly tell me if there's another way of doing this or if its the correct procedure as I am trying to retrieve data from University survey (its a tutorial im working on). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The code you have could be simplified to:

```
let Q6i = data
          |> List.filter (fun r -> question r = 12 && score r >= 100)
          |> List.map (fun r -> subject r, institution r)
```

By the way, could you please provide more details about what `data` is?

Comment: @ takemy oxygen sure I can as its a tutorial thanks ever soo much im quite new to the language im trying to finish off the tutorial which would allow me to finish off the course work. 

whats your email and I can send it to you as its quite lengthy to post on here thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

If I want to find a set of two int in F# Whats the best command to use i.e Give the year and month which had the highest sunny day. Thanks